# Angular limitTo with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-limitto

I am using a angularjs filter method on an repeated array of items and trying to filter numbers with a limitTo filter.

This is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23rexnp8/19/) code

The filter is working fine but I have a condition `ng-if="!o.IsFeaturedEvent"` and filter should apply to the event list which is not `IsFeaturedEvent`.  Currently it is applying on all the events

How can I use limitto with ng-if condition

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom filter like this:

```
.filter('nonFeaturedEvent', function() {
  return events => events.filter(e => !e.IsFeaturedEvent);
})
```

And apply it *before* your limit to, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="o in data  | nonFeaturedEvent | limitTo:limit"  ng-if="!o.IsFeaturedEvent">
```

The `nonFeaturedEvent` filter will remove all featured events before passing to the `limitTo` filter.

[Here's a link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeisenberg/vxhzm703/3/) for this idea. It's a bit of a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ng-if, use filter to do it.

I tested your code with 
`"o in data | filter: !o.IsFeaturedEvent | limitTo:limit "`

It displays the first event, which is a featured event.

If you want to display non-featured events, then use

`"o in data | filter: o.IsFeaturedEvent | limitTo:limit "`